# How to copy a file in Meson to a subdirectory

Tags: meson-build

My application uses a Glade file and also cached data in a JSON file. When I do the following, everything works okay as long as the user installs the application with `ninja install`

```
    #Install cached JSON file
    install_data(
        join_paths('data', 'dataCache.json'),
        install_dir: join_paths('myapp', 'resources')
    )
    #Install the user interface glade file
    install_data(
        join_paths('src', 'MainWindow.glade'),
        install_dir: join_paths('myapp', 'resources')
    )
```

The downside is that the user needs to install the application. I want the user to be able to just build the application with `ninja` and run it without installing it if they don't want to install it on their system. The problem is that when I do

```
    #Copy the cached JSON file to the build output directory
    configure_file(input : join_paths('data', 'dataCache.json'),
        output : join_paths('myapp', 'resources', 'dataCache.json'),
        copy: true
    )

    #Copy the Glade file to the build output directory
    configure_file(input : join_paths('src', 'MainWindow.glade'),
        output : join_paths('myapp', 'resources', 'MainWindow.glade'),
        copy: true
    )
```

I get **ERROR:  Output file name must not contain a subdirectory.**

Is there a way to run `ninja` and have it create the directories `myapp/resources` on the build folder and then copy the Glade and JSON file there to be used as resources? Such as to let the user run the application without having to do `ninja install`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by making a script and call it from Meson.

For example, in a file `copy.py` that takes the relative input and output paths as arguments:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3 

import os, sys, shutil

# get absolute input and output paths
input_path = os.path.join(
    os.getenv('MESON_SOURCE_ROOT'), 
    os.getenv('MESON_SUBDIR'),
    sys.argv[1])

output_path = os.path.join(
    os.getenv('MESON_BUILD_ROOT'), 
    os.getenv('MESON_SUBDIR'),
    sys.argv[2])

# make sure destination directory exists
os.makedirs(os.path.dirname(output_path), exist_ok=True)

# and finally copy the file
shutil.copyfile(input_path, output_path)
```

and then in your `meson.build` file:

```
copy = find_program('copy.py')

run_command(
    copy,
    join_paths('src', 'dataCache.json'), 
    join_paths('myapp', 'resources', 'dataCache.json')
)
run_command(
    copy, 
    join_paths('src', 'MainWindow.glade'), 
    join_paths('myapp', 'resources', 'MainWindow.glade')
)
```

Answer (score 4):

https://mesonbuild.com/Fs-module.html#copyfile

```py
copy = fs.copyfile('input-file', 'output-file')
```